# confusion matrix plot is unable to show values within plot

Tags: data-science, data-analysis, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot confusion matrix, but the plot seems unable to show values at the center.

```
Code : 
plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size":20}, 
            cmap='Blues', square=True, fmt='.2f')
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.title('Confusion matrix for:\n{}'.format(model.__class__.__name__));
```

Output :
[image]

How to have the values 0.45, 0.94, 0.06 and 0.55 to be at the center of square box for better readability ?

Answer (score 1):

The figure size appears to be too small - `4x2`. Also, you are making `square=True`, the size is not right.
As I dont have the same model, I tried it with another model and this is the code and output

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
sns.heatmap((metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, svmGridtest_predict)),annot=True, 
            annot_kws={"size":20}, fmt='.2f', square=True, cmap='Blues')
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actuals',rotation=0)
plt.title('Confusion matrix for:\n{}'.format('SVM'))
```

OUTPUT figure here...

[image: My Confusion Matrix]

Comment: Thanks, I tried on different version of python and Jupyter notebook and it worked. Still not sure if Python and Jupyter notebook version was causing the issue.

Comment: Good it worked. I am using python 3.8.5 and jupyter notebook. For fig size (4,20 it was giving error you showed and resolved on increasing the fig size.. Do close the question with any steps you took so it would be helpful for others as well